# Wordpress ACF repeater saved as JSON

Tags: php, wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

ACF repeater is getting saved as serialized JSON

I have the following snippet

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
            $result[] = array(
                'id'       => $item->id,
                'name'     => $item->name,
                'position' => $item->position,
            );
        }


 update_field("my_repeater", $result, $sPostID);
```

but at the end I get the fields saved as serialized JSON

How to debug this issue?

Comment: Why is that an issue? That is the correct behaviour- it is how ACF saves the information. If you use the appropriate ACF update and get functions, it shouldn't matter how it is stored.